# In Javascript FireFox does not allow resizing div by dragging

Tags: javascript, firefox, resize, draggable, textselection

I have a div with border and in its right-bottom corner I have image for resizing:

[image]

So when user presses mouse on the image, he (or she) can drag mouse and resize the div.

This works fine in all browsers but FireFox.

In FireFox something strange happens: after the user presses mouse and starts dragging, the cursor changes to:

[image]

So the cursor changes to this one and mouse move events are not coming, when the mouse is dragged.

I am wondering, what causes this behaviour. I thought maybe FireFox thinks that the user is trying to select text by pressing and dragging the mouse. But I cancelled text selection using this code:

```
resizeImageImg.onselectstart          = "return false;";
resizeImageImg.ondragstart            = "return false;";

resizeImageImg.style.WebkitUserSelect = 'none';
resizeImageImg.style.KhtmlUserSelect  = 'none';
resizeImageImg.style.MozUserSelect    = 'none';
resizeImageImg.style.MsUserSelect     = 'none';
resizeImageImg.style.OUserSelect      = 'none';
resizeImageImg.style.UserSelect       = 'none';

resizeImageImg.setAttribute ("unselectable", "on");
resizeImageImg.setAttribute ("draggable",    "false");
```

(for both: the div and the resize image)

But this did not solve the problem. FireFox still does not let resizing and changes cursor to "not-allowed".

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, I found the solution.

I replaced:

```
resizeImageImg.ondragstar = "return false;";
```

by

```
resizeImageImg.ondragstart = function () { return false; };
```

and it started working in FireFox as well.

What happens here is that if you want to process mouse-move events when your mouse-down event came from an image, then you have to make you image not-draggable. But this is not enough to use

```
resizeImageImg.setAttribute ("draggable", false);
```

(at least in FireFox) becasuse events ondragstart are still coming. I understood this when I set:

```
resizeImageImg.ondragstart = function () { alert ("ondragstart"); return false; };
```

So I realized that FireFox does not obbey setAttribute ("draggable", false) - whilst other browsers do.

Answer (score 0):

Andy, here is the solution I have come up with. I have gone to great effort to make it quick and easy to use.

You can view the file here:
http://files.social-library.org/stackoverflow/imageResizer.html

It is simple to use. Create your image and specify a width and height. Then, once the page loads call the function imageResizer.init(imageObject) sending the image object as a parameter. It will then set the image up with the dragger.

This works in firefox, chrome and internet explorer 8+.

Comment: Thanks, I checked your solution, it is cool. My one is similar (I cannot give a link to it, because it is a private project and you need login/password to access). But for some reason in my solution some browsers did not let the mouse-move events pass through. IE did allow. So I understood, that my resize-image (the red diagonal stripes) should set attribute ondragstart = function () { return false; };  so the browser will not process mouse-move events and will let my function to process them.